# How to use watchdog to monitor whenever a file created or deleted in Python

Tags: python, watchdog

I am using `watchdog` in `Python` to monitor realtime whenever a file is created or deleted.

Following examples, I tried with the following:

```
import time
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        print("File is created!")

event_handler = MyHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, path='C:/daten/dog.txt', recursive=False)

observer.start()

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()

observer.join()
```

Of course, the file `path='C:/daten/dog.txt'` does not exist when this script begins to run. But I still get error messages as

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Why it's telling me it cannot find the file specified at the first place. I need it running to watch for the creation of the file after all.

---

**Update:**
Now I understand that `watchdog` is for monitoring a folder rather than a file.

Is there a similar package for monitoring a file or is it just better done by `while` and `sleep` statements together?

Comment: provide the ```path``` only not the file. eg. ```path = 'C:/daten/'``` and then copy paste a file or create a file in this folder

Answer (score 2):

> Why it's telling me it cannot find the file specified at the first place.

Because the path you give to watchdog is where it's going to hook itself to listen for events.

You can't watch a file and expect its creation event to be recorded. File creation events are posted on the parent directory, so *that* is what you should be watching.

In fact I don't know that watching a specific file makes any sense with watchdog, its tagline is

> **Directory** monitoring made easy with

Comment: Exactly this was the case with me. I migrated my script from Linux to Windows, and it wasn't working. I think it's because of windows behaviour that it post modify events to the parent directory!